# Failed to access the WSDL at: https://example.com?wsdl. It failed with: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, wsdl, keytool

Trying create ***wsdl*** client from https://example.com?wsdl. 
Using this command ***wsimport -keep https://example.com?wsdl***

I have already Installed ssl certificate by using this command
***keytool -import -alias ctp -file C:\Users\ravi\Desktop\ctplive.cer -keystore C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\security\cacerts***

I am using Window10, Jdk1.8.

Full Error log

Failed to access the WSDL at: https://example.com?wsdl. It failed with: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you import the certificate into the Keystore that your JAVA application is using. On Windows or Linux, you might have more than one JRE installed e.g. a standalone JRE, not under your JDK e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jre..\..\cacerts`.

The first thing to do is to check which JRE your application is referencing, you start by checking if you have `%JAVA_HOME%` (`$JAVA_HOME` if on Linux) env variable set, this is where usually SSL implementation of JAVA look to find your JRE's `cacerts` file.

On Windows command line you can find all your JAVAs installation with:

```
where java
```

On Linux:

```
where java
which java
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply I have checked my jdk path and imported certificate in correct jdk which is in enviorment variable . but still not working facing same issue.

Comment: OK, first list all `cacerts` file you might have, you can do that on Windows with `dir /S "cacerts"` and import the certificate to all of them, you don't know which Keystore might be in use. If that doesn't work, check your JVM properties are not overriding the default path of the Keystore `System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore")` & `System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore")` if none is set then it is defaulting to the `cacerts` file of the running JRE.